# .NET 7 Reading bundled assembly from self contained single file app

Tags: c#, .net-core, runtime

I made a .NET 7 compiler that compiles plugins for another process. The compiler is a Self-Contained single file executable so it can easily run in multiple environments. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to read bundled dependencies that can be shared with the parent process.

**Things I've tried**

- Reading main assembly manifest (Non existent)
- Assembly.Location (Null in single file executables)
- AppContext.BaseDirectory (Doesn't really help)
- System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory() (Same as AppContext.BaseDirectory)

I'm out of ideas and everything I've googled has come back to reading the resource manifest which doesn't contain anything.

**Expected Behavior:**
Lets say a plugin requires **System.Collections.Immutable.dll** the compiler would need to reference that in the compilation to be able to emit it. The emitted assembly plus all the resolved references would need to be streamed back to the parent process so it can be loaded and all the references can be resolved.